# Popup blocking in Google Chrome causing issues with Capybara/Rspec tests

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, capybara, popup-blocker

I'm writing some automated tests using Capybara/RSpec,  I choose/configure the driver by using this little bit of ruby:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

I'm testing whether or not a button I click is opening a popup window and that the window is displaying the content it should.  The issue is that when the test opens the window, the Google Chrome popup blocker blocks it, causing the tests to fail.  Disabling the blocker from the options menu does not work.  Also, I'm afraid that once I run these on the server it will cause the same issue.

Is there a way to disable the popup block for the tests automatically?

Comment: +1!  we're having the same problem when using selenium WebDriver (chromedriver) to run automated tests...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a very similar problem.  Like John says, the command-line switch no longer works.  We tried using a custom profile, but it seemed to be overwritten.

Eventually solved it by *manually* disabling popups using `WebDriver` itself:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/advanced')
driver.find_element_by_id('privacyContentSettingsButton').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('popups').click()
```

Which, I guess, is more like what the user would do anyway ;-)

Comment: I assume this would be done as a precondition test setup() before running the actual test right? Thanks for this tip.

Comment: This is great, but how do you actually find out the element by name? When my browser launches from Selenium, I have no option to right-click and then "Inspect", presumably because the popup itself is preventing me from interacting with the browser. EDIT: I solved my own problem. I can reference the button by its associated text (In my case, "You are not an authorized user"). Then I can use Selenium to click it.

Answer (score 8):

You can call driver with options.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-popup-blocking)
```

This is mentioned on the [RubyBindings](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) page on the Selenium wiki.

Comment: I have already tried that but I get the following error:   unknown option: {:switches=>["--disable-popup-blocking"]}

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest version of the selenium-webdriver gem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, at the moment.  Having the same problem.  It doesn't appear that in the current version of chrome, that disabling the popup blocker is a command line switch any more.

http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc&exact_package=chromium

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript Version**

You can do in JavaScript like so...

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome.js');
var options = new chrome
              .Options()
              .addArguments('-incognito', '--disable-popup-blocking');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000);

return driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with latest chrome driver, try this

```
css_selector_for_iframe = 'iframe[name="settings"]'

driver.get('chrome://settings/content')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector_for_iframe)
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_name('popups').click()
click_element(driver, '#content-settings-overlay-confirm')
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following setting 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
and it works correctly .. It disable all pops up

Comment: "--disable-web-security" sounds like a flag NOT to be switched off just for a popup blocking behaviour...