# How to block the pop-up windows in chrome by Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the java and selenium to write the test script for automation. On here the target automated Org has some reminder pop-up windows so it makes the confusion of taking in the command of **driver.getWindowHandles()** command on my results.

I try the below code to try to **Block the pop-up windows on the chrome**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//chrome path in system//");
    ChromeOptions options  = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", "disable-popup-blocking");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But it's not working it's given the below error and prevent the chrome to launch:

> **from unknown error: cannot parse excludeSwitches**
>   **from unknown error: must be a list**

So what I should do for close those pop-up windows. Any answer is appreciated. I am using the **chrome version:  '2.29.461591'** and **java.version: '1.8.0_92'**

Comment: Have a look at this workaround... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742852/popup-blocking-in-google-chrome-causing-issues-with-capybara-rspec-tests. I think you should look at the answer by "Md. Nazmul Haque Sarker" as it seems more relevant to current chrome verion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am a new bee for a test automation. I am not understanding clearly on that link. on your suggested answer.


css_selector_for_iframe = 'iframe[name="settings"]'

driver.get('chrome://settings/content')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector_for_iframe)
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_name('popups').click()
click_element(driver, '#content-settings-overlay-confirm')
driver.switch_to_default_content()

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the `"disable-popup-blocking"` argument by type-casting it as a list.
This works for me in python:

```py
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])
```

Comment: no luck for this....

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code it is working fine for me:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//chrome path in system//");
    ChromeOptions options  = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("incognito");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Sorry dude. It launches the chrome in the as an incognito window but it's failed to block the pop-up Browser window on running my automation test script :(

Comment: Updated the code for you, may be -- needs to added to set the chrome option on your env.

Comment: "needs to add to set the chrome option on your env." means I have done for the block the pop-up windows for manually..?
Because it's also failed to block the pop-up Browser windows for chrome in my test :(

Comment: unfortunately for selenium 4 i tried this but not working guys!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for in 2024-02, Python

```py
prefs = {
  "download.default_directory": "./",
  "credentials_enable_service": False,
  "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
  "excludeSwitches": ["disable-popup-blocking"]
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```