# How to upgrade Browser in capybara with capybara webkit -cucumber?

Tags: reactjs, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am getting upgrade browser popup , when i click on button but i am using capybra version 2.4.4 and capybara webkit 1.15.0.

-> For the solution i changed differnt capybara versions like(2.7.1,2.13.0) but still i am getting upgrade browser popup.
Any suggestions to overcome this issue.

Comment: have you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743228/1033737 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR - You can't

Longer answer: The upgrade browser popup isn't based on the version of `capybara` you're using (2.4.4 is really old btw - latest is 3.4.2), it's based on the `capybara-webkit` driver. `capybara-webkit` is built on QtWebkit which stopped development quite a few years ago. There has been an effort to revive QtWebkit and bring it up to date but `capybara-webkit` isn't compatible with that currently. This means `capybara-webkit` is basically equivalent to a 6 year old version of Safari today and can't really be updated. You're going to have much better compatibility with modern web apps if you swap to using headless chrome or firefox via selenium.

Comment: I upgraded capybara version 2.16.0 but still i getting upgrade browser popup.As per project i want use ruby version 2.2 but i tried to upgrade capybara latest version its asking me to upgrade ruby version -its not possible for me to upgrade ruby as per project restructions

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy As I stated in my answer - the problem is not the version of Capybara it's the fact that `capybara-webkit` (`capybara` and `capybara-webkit` are different things) is based on old technology.  You can't get rid of that warning and stay with `capybara-webkit`.